# Help commenting for the low rep

Tags: support, comment, new-users

When reviewing low quality vote we might see some comments posted incorrectly as an answer.

Most of the time, if their comments are meaningful, I will copy their comments and paste it to the correct intended place. Is that a "correct/desirable" action? Or is there any other options or should I just click "recommend deletion" and move on?

Comment: Moderators are able to convert answers into comments. If the comment is really worth it you can flag the answer asking them to do that (bear in mind, they have a lot of work).

Answer (score 1):

"Meaningful" is not the same as "adds value". The decision to preserve the text should be based on whether the Q&A would significantly lose in value if that text did not exist.

Nearly always, the answer is no.

Comment: I disagree with you. IMO every added value to a post should be kept. Or equivalently, we should not lower the quality of a post. Of course, these comments should not stay in answer format, but an improvement is an improvement and it should not completely disappear. Moreover, how much is "significantly"?

Comment: "Nearly always, the answer is no." Perhaps you can support that anecdotally?

Comment: @les I"m second in LQ reviews behind Davide Giraudo... I've seen things, and very few of them made me think "I wish this person had 50 points".